# Doubles and Arithmetic

Tags: c++, visual-c++, math, numbers, date-arithmetic

I compile and run this code with MSVC2008

```
long double x = 111111111;
long double y = 222222222;
long double Z = x * y;

cout << z << endl;
```

When I debug, `z` equals

```
24691357975308640
```

Mathematically `z` should be

```
24691357975308642
```

What's going on ?

Comment: I get 24691357975308642 with gcc. Blame your compiler.

Comment: @a-z what's long long MAX value and how much bytes 1 long long takes ?

Comment: It is 64 bit long and `signed long long` can store [-9223372036854775808, 9223372036854775807]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doubles are only precise to around [16 digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). If I counted right, then you have 17 digits, and are correct up to 16. If you want to do this kind of math, and will only have integers, then use ints. For a number that large, you will need to use `uint64_t`.

Comment: @jonas: You could always use long ints, which are 64 bit integers. That should do just fine.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto: longs aren't guaranteed to hold 64 bits. long longs are.

Comment: @Alex: That's not true. A long long is simply guaranteed to be at least as large as a long.

Comment: @sharth: Please (re)read the C standard, section `5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types <limits.h>`.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is going on. Doubles have a finite amount of precision, and for that precision the value that you obtain is correct. It is an unfortunate shortcoming of the way you chose to print the value that information about the precision (i.e. the significant digits) was lost.

For example, for a 1+11+(1)+52 float ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format)), we have 53 bits of precision, giving us 53 × log<sub>10</sub>2 de­ci­mal digits of precision, i.e. 15. So we only print 15 digits:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setprecision(15) << std::scientific
          << Z << std::endl;
```

The result is:

```
2.469135797530864e+16
```

Now we made the precision manifest, and the result is indeed correct at that precision.

If you don't like the magic `15` in the code, you should `#include <limits>` and use:

```
std::numeric_limits<decltype(Z)>::digits10
```

Answer (score 1):

Floating point arithmetic is going on. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is a good read. Basically, computers can problems storing and dealing with floating point numbers, so you get these sorts of arithmetic errors.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, one can write a book answering your question. Long story short - floating point arithmetic is going on. See [Floating Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). Also, converting double values  to ASCII (for displaying) is also hard and not precise. You may also want to look at [arbitrary precision arithmetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).